# Attrs dependant attributes on initialization

Tags: python, python-attrs

Let's say we have an `attrs` class:

```python
@attr.s()
class Foo:
    a: bool = attr.ib(default=False)
    b: int = attr.ib(default=5)
    
    @b.validator
    def _check_b(self, attribute, value):
        if not self.a:
            raise ValueError("to define 'b', 'a' must be True")
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("'b' has to be a positive integer")
```

So the following behaviour is correct:

```python
>>> Foo(a=True, b=10)
Foo(a=True, b=10)

>>> Foo(b=10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<attrs generated init __main__.Foo>", line 5, in __init__
    __attr_validator_b(self, __attr_b, self.b)
  File "<input>", line 9, in _check_b
ValueError: to define 'b', 'a' must be True
```

But this is not:

```python
>>> Foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<attrs generated init __main__.Foo>", line 5, in __init__
    __attr_validator_b(self, __attr_b, self.b)
  File "<input>", line 9, in _check_b
ValueError: to define 'b', 'a' must be True
```

This obviously happens because `Foo.b` is always initialized, regardless of when `Foo.a` is given value: via default value or on `Foo.__init__`.

Is there anyway to accomplish this attribute dependance with any of the initialization hooks?

Answer (score 1):

Following [@hynek's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68661553/16592848) to have default values that result in a valid instance, I've changed `default` of the dependant attribute to `None` to validate only when a value is passed on `__init__`:

```python
@attr.s()
class Foo:
    a: bool = attr.ib(default=False)
    b: Optional[int] = attr.ib(default=None)
    
    @b.validator
    def _check_b(self, attribute, value):
        if value is None:
            self.b = 5
            return
        if not self.a:
            raise ValueError("to define 'b', 'a' must be True")
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("'b' has to be a positive integer")
```

I am aware that to change attributes's values on a validator is not optimal, but it gets the work done.

Documentation about validators can be found [here](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html#validators)

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you want to do, you can check whether `value` is the default value (available on `attribute.default`). However, your whole problem is that the default values result in an instance that's, according to your validator, invalid. Thus there's probably better ways to model this.

Comment: The problem is that I can't differentitate between a value given in the `__init__` and the `attribute.default`. I've tried the approach to have default values that yields a valid instance.

Comment: I think the most straight-forward solution would be to use some kind of sentinel value as defaults and the use `__attrs_post_init__` to replace them with actual defaults and do your validation. As you correctly say here: your problem is less about dependent attributes and more about detecting whether or not an argument has been passed vs default.